# Can't get values from textbox to class

Tags: php, class, oop, textbox

I want to make a basic calculator. Every thing is set, the textboxes and buttons. It needs to be OOP, but that gives me problems. It worked before until I tried to do it in OOP.

I don't get errors but when ever I try to let the code calculate a sum, it results the answer as 0. Its probably because the class doesn't get the values from the textboxes, but I don't know how to fix it.

Code of the class where the calculation needs to be:

```
class CountUp
{
    public static $_sum;
    public static $number1;
    public static $number2;

    public function __construct()
    {
            self::$_sum;
            self::$number1;
            self::$number2;
    }

    public function getnumber1()
    {    
    self::$number1 = ($_POST['number1']);
    return self::$number1;
    }

    public function getnumber2()
    {
    self::$number2 = ($_POST['number2']);
    return self::$number2;
    }

    public static function getsum()
    {
    $_sum = self::$number1 + self::$number2;
    return $_sum;
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm bad at php.

EDIT: This is where the values are supossed the come from:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name ="btw calculate" method="post" action="test2.php"><br/>
        enter a number <br/>
        <input type="tekst" name="number1" value=""><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="plus" value="+">
        <input type="submit" name="retract"  value="- "><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="divide" value="/ ">
        <input type="submit" name="multiply" value="* "><br/>
        enter a second number <br/>
        <input type="tekst" name="number2" value=""><br/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT2: I'm an idiot, forgot to add this part to this question:

```
<?php
include("plus.class.php");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if (isset($_POST['plus']))
    {
        echo CountUp::getSum();
    }

    else
    {
        //still empty for now
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please show the code using the methods. You probably never call `getnumberX()` and hence `$numberX` isn't set

Comment: how do you sending values to this class?

Comment: @kingkero Added the other forms in the OP.

Comment: the form is wrong, in that 'operator' should be a 'select field' of some sort. The major problem with the 'CountUp' class, ignoring the merits of the approach, are the mixture of 'static' and 'instance' methods. Also, you do not execute the 'getNumber1' and 'getNumber2' methods, means that the variables are never set.

Comment: @RyanVincent I don't really understand what you mean, mind if you show it to me?

Comment: Edited to show a form, get the input then add the number together from the $_POST array.

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks, it worked. I'm going to study(mess) your code a little, so I know how it exactly works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up static functions which are related to the class definition.

And object instance functions, which are related to each 'new' 'instance' of a class you create.

Here in an input form and the class adding the $_POST array values together.

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST['number1'])) {

// object instance version
class CountUp
{
    private $number1 = 0;
    private $number2 = 0;


    public function setNumber1($number)
    {
        $this->number1 = $number;
    }

    public function setNumber2($number)
    {
        $this->number2 = ($number)

    public function getSum()
    {
        $_sum = $this->number1 + $this->number2;
        return $_sum;
    }
}

    $addTwoNumbers1 = new CountUp();
    $addTwoNumbers1->setNumber1($_POST['number1']);
    $addTwoNumbers1->setNumber2($_POST['number2']);
    ?>
    <p> The answer of: <?= $_POST['number1']?> + <?= $_POST['number2'] ?> = <?= $addTwoNumbers1->getSum(); ?>
    <?php
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name ="btw calculate" method="post" action=""><br/>
        enter a number <br/>
        <input type="text" name="number1" value=""><br/>
        <p>will be added to...</p>
        enter a second number <br/>
        <input type="text" name="number2" value=""><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="plus" value="add the two numbers together...">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: then how does the numbers whom the user put in the form gets into the class?